# Initial value in the Django CharField does not have any effect

Tags: django, forms

I've looked at many pages on this site and a few others, but none of the solutions seems to work. Specifically,

```
class twoFieldGeneric(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.label1  = kwargs.pop('label1')
       self.label2  = kwargs.pop('label2')
       self.init1   = kwargs.pop('init1')
       self.init2   = kwargs.pop('init2')
       super(twoFieldGeneric, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['field1'] = forms.CharField(required=False, initial=self.init1, label=self.label1)
       self.fields['field2'] = forms.CharField(required=False, initial=self.init2, label=self.label2)
```

does not result in the initial values being set.

What and I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not define the fields at the class level?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, too, but the initial value is still not set. Besides, how would I then make it configurable?

Comment: You haven't shown how you are initializing the `twoFieldGeneric` form in the view.

Comment: See the docs on [dynamic initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).

Comment: `juuidSelector = twoFieldGeneric(request.POST, label1="Job UUID", init1=j_uuid, label2="Data Type", init2=d_type)`

Comment: @Daniel - yes I did before I posted this.

Comment: So, why are you not doing what's in that doc then?